# Kriyas Yam Suf and Naḥshon ben Amminadav

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, midrash, beshalach, yetziat-mitzrayim

By Kriyas Yam Suf it says that the first one to Jump in was Naḥchshon ben Amminadav. My question is: why didn't Moshe Rabbenu jump in first?

Comment: Well, it could be that he found it hard to swim when his hands were occupied according to Hashem's command.  But this is a simchashatorah question, so it's gotta be something better than that ;)

Comment: I have to admit its not my question Rabbi Reisman in his Navi shiur tonight mentioned it and I am just looking for an answer?

Comment: @simchashatorah I believe this is a medrash, so to answer the question properly, a citation of the medrash I believe is in order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moshe Rabbenu already had complete faith in Gd. It was up to Klal Yisroel to show their faith.

Comment: MordechaiDuman, welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for your interesting idea! If you could source this idea it would greatly improve your answer. Please also consider registering your account to gain full access to the site. I look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is backwards.  The question should be, why does the midrash suggest that Nachshon, was the first to enter the Yam Suf?

It seems, that the midrash about him entering the Yam Suf, was a response to the fact that Nachshon gives the offering to the Mishkan first, while earlier, he is listed 5th.  This is explained by saying that Moshe could not decide who should go first, but all the other princes and leaders pointed to Nachshon, saying that since he went first into the ocean sanctifying Gd's name, then here too, he should go first and sanctify Gd's Mishkan.

As to why the sea did not split until somebody walked into it, perhaps it was a counterpoint to the fact that Gd just fought a war for the Jewish people, and soon the Jewish people would have to fight wars themselves.  A sign of trust in Hashem to split the ocean was needed by the Jewish people to prove that we could "open the eye of the needle", before Hashem would "create an opening as wide as two camels."    Since Moshe had direct knowledge of Hashem's abilities and miracles, he himself could not fulfill that function, and some other leader of the Jewish people would have to do that.

Comment: nice answer to your question! NOT MINE!!!!!!!!

Comment: @simchashatorah Then clarify your question.